# Django-Simple-Captcha Cron Job To Delete Captcha Records

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cron, captcha

I need some help with making a cron job for django-simple-captcha to be able to delete captcha database records from postgresql captcha_captchastore table on a daily basis or an hourly basis. Inside the captcha_captchastore table there is an expiration datetime column. According to the docs and the maintainer himself, you can use:

CAPTCHA_GET_FROM_POOL, CAPTCHA_GET_FROM_POOL_TIMEOUT, CAPTCHA_TIMEOUT settings

combined with python3 manage.py captcha_create_pool command.

But the docs are a bit confusing and do not show you an example of how to do the cron job with postgres.

I also do not know in production if it is good to run the python3 manage.py captcha_create_pool while the site is actively running in gunicorn. Does gunicorn need to be stopped to be able to run the captcha_creat_pool command with a cron job?

Can any of the django packages below be used to make this easier? If so, how?

I would prefer if someone gave a nice example or description of how to do this.

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/cron/

https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code I use to run cron jobs using Django.

```
"""
Add this file to user crontab
# crontab -u username -e
* * * * *       python /your/path/to/this/file.py

"""

"""
This prefix is copied from wsgi.py
"""

import os
import sys

execfile('/your/path/bin/activate_this.py', dict(__file__='/your/path/bin/activate_this.py'))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append("/your/path/project/")

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

# You will have access to Django models from here

from your.models import MyModel

# Call to staticmethod delete_old_items
MyModel.delete_old_items()
```